# MySQL - LEFT JOIN not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

```
attribute
=========
ID  Name
-------------------
1   Size
2   Colour


product_attribute
=========
ID  attribute_id
-------------------
1   1
```

I want to show any values contained in the attribute table that are missing from the product_attribute table.

This code results in "size" when I expected "colour".  What am I missing?

```
SELECT name FROM attribute a LEFT JOIN product_attribute p ON a.id = p.attribute_id
```

Comment: This would return both.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT a.name FROM attribute a 
LEFT JOIN product_attribute p ON a.id = p.attribute_id
where p.attribute_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this instead :

```
SELECT name FROM attribute where ID  not in (select attribute_id from product_attribute)
```

Comment: And what will happen if the inner query will return null? Hint: the query won't work.

Comment: When product_attribute has no data in it, it will not return null it will return empty

Comment: To comply with the SQL standard, IN returns NULL not only if the expression on the left hand side is NULL, but also if no match is found in the list and one of the expressions in the list is NULL. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in